# How do I run a headless testnet on OS X?

Tags: bitcoind, mac, testnet

I'm trying to develop some applications and need `bitcoind`, but can't seem to find a recent version. Posts seem to indicate that it's incorporated into Bitcoin-Qt, but I don't want to run a GUI just for headless RPC calls.

So how do I set up a testnet on OS X?

[How to setup testnet-in-a-box on Mac OSX?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-testnet-in-a-box-on-mac-osx) seems like it would work, except I don't have the `bitcoind` command for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ready to use distribution of bitcoind for Mac OS X doesn't exist, so you would have to build it from source code, here is the instructions for that: [What are the steps in building bitcoind on Mac OS X 10.6?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/793/what-are-the-steps-in-building-bitcoind-on-mac-os-x-10-6)

Answer (score 1):

You could also install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), then run the command `brew install bitcoin` then you will have bitcoind installed.